# Calendar Tag Entry Fields Not Showing

Tags: entries, tags, calendar, calendar-events

EE 5.2.2

Using the `{exp:channel:calendar}` tag, I'm not able to get custom fields from within the `{entries}` tag.

example:

```
{exp:channel:calendar channel="showtimes"}
    {if entries}
        {entries}
            {title} // does show
            {showtime} // a custom text field, does not show
        {/entries}
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:calendar}
```

There also isn't any problem calling things like `author` or `entry_date`, but my custom fields are not showing and it's vital that they do.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calendar tag doesn't support custom fields. Either use a channel:entries tag, or something like the Solspace Calendar module if you need more flexibility with things like recurring dates.

Comment: Good answer! From this I tested putting a channel entry tag inside the `if entries` conditional based on the `entry_id` like so:
`{if entries}    
 {entries}
  {exp:channel:entries channel="showtimes" entry_id="{entry_id}" show_future_entries="yes"}
   {movies:title}
  {/exp:channel:entries}
 {/entries}
{/if}`
And that appears to be working just fine. Thanks so much!